# The method of undetermined coeficients for a non-homogenous linear ODE with a rational RHS

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the equation $$\ddot x-5\dot x+4x=\frac{9e^t}{1+e^{-3t}}$$ The characteristic roots are one and four. The solution to the homogenous equation is $C_1e^t+C_2e^{4t}$.

How can we find a particular solution to the equation? Can we use the method of undetermined coefficients? If so what would be the form of the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set $$x(t) = C_1(t) x_1(t),$$ where $x_i(t) = e^{s_i t}$, $s_i = \{1,4\}$ (you can chose any of the roots). Differentiate now to obtain $x'$ and $x''$ and substitute back into the original ODE. Take into account that $x_1'' - 5x_1'+ 4x_1 = 0$ and solve for $C_1$.

Can you take it from here? Let us know.

Cheers!

Comment: This looks like the method of variation of coeficients, exept you consider $C_1(t)x_1(t)$ instead of $C_1(t)x_1(t)+C_2(t)x_2(t)$.

Comment: Precisely! I think this method is a bit faster.